# how to design master page in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, look-and-feel

every one 
i m new with ASP .net and I dont know how to create master page with ASP .nethelp me plz

---

This is my `Masterpage` Markup:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        &nbsp;<table style="width: 874px; height: 592px">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height: 9px">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#C0C000" Text="Sarth Enterprises"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="height: 15px">
                    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="Products">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="AE" Value="AE"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="RSQE" Value="RSQE"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Comp. Hardware" Value="Comp. Hardware"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Contact us" Value="Contact us"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="About us" Value="About us"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="FAQ" Value="FAQ"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </Items>
                    </asp:Menu>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 106px; height: 15px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 212px">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Member Login"></asp:Label><br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="User ID:"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="For new member,"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Sign UP</asp:HyperLink></td>
                <td style="width: 257px">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 106px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#C0C000" Height="19px"
                        Text="Copy right ,resereved @ Sarth enterprises" Width="284px"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically is giving you trouble? Are you having trouble writing it at all? Do you now know hot to associate a content page to a master page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master Pages allow you to define the look and feel of an entire website. The following links come from Microsoft. Check them out:

[ASP.NET Master Pages Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

[Master Pages Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28sf10gzjodvrpce55el2p5cnk%29%29/learn/master-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehszf8ax%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) MSDN page (Walkthrough: Creating and Using ASP.NET Master Pages in Visual Web Developer):

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of your Web site, and then click AddNew Item.
- Under Visual Studio installed templates, click Master Page.
- In the Name box, type Master1.
- Select the Place code in separate file check box.

Comment: yeah i have done all these things..
after that..
I have delete contentplaceholder from design side of master page..
then i have taken 1 table of 3*3.. then i design some structure..
but after debug and run it shows nothing on output Screen

Comment: How about updating your question and posting the code of your master page? That _might_ give us enough clues as to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the creation of a master page offered by Oded, you want to leave the "contentPlaceholders".  And you can add more as you see fit.  This is the location that your derived pages will make use of.

When you are ready to create a page based on the master page, click to add a new form for your project, click the checkbox to use a "master page", and give it the name of the new form you want to create.  When you click OK, it will prompt you for which master page you want it to be based on (you can actually create MANY master pages).  Once picked and you are in design mode, it will show you in a greyed out look, the actual content as coming from the "master page", and the content placeholder is where you put your stuff specific to that page.  Tables, Grids, labels, whatever.  Save and run and you'll see your content.  Then, adjust the master page and put something in like a company logo graphic, save and run your second form, you'll see that it will now have the newly added logo.

Hope this clarifies HOW they work... Additionally, you can drag/drop a CSS file onto a master page to apply style formatting across the board too.